# How to diagnose occasionally freezing computer

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, freeze, desktop-computer

#### The problem

I have a desktop computer running Windows 10. Since about 1 year, I have been experiencing occasional freezes where the computer stops responding and has to be reset manually. I've tried waiting for a few hours once and it didn't recover on its own.

#### Observations

The first thing I've checked is the memory. I've tested the memory with MemTest86 and found no errors.

The event viewer also doesn't contain anything relevant.

One thing I've noticed is that this seems to happen more frequently when the ambient temperature is high. Now that it is summer, and the ambient temperature in my office is almost 30ºC, it seems to be happening more.

In the winter, the computer froze more frequently while playing video games or while encoding video, although it sometimes freezes while doing lighter tasks. I've tried updating the video drivers, and also installing older versions, but that didn't seem to help.

The last suspicious thing is a USB hub that I have that sometimes has a bad contact. If I touch the wire, the devices that are connected to it are reset, but the PC itself seems fine.

#### What I tried

I tried monitoring the system with OpenHardwareMonitor and checking the sensors from a different computer (using the HTTP interface) but couldn't see any strange values when the computer freezes.

I also ran some stress tests with MSI Afterburner / MSI Kombustor, but couldn't get the computer to freeze while the tests were running.

Monitoring the sensors and doing a CPU stress test causes it to reach high temperatures, but the system remains stable:

[image: Screenshot of the sensors status]

Since the CPU is being stressed, I suppose it is expected to reach such high temperatures. During a warm day and normal usage, the CPU temperature remains around 60ºC.

#### Here's the main hardware:

- CPU: Intel Core i9-9900K @3.60 GHz
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER
- Motherboard: MSI MPG Z390 GAMING EDGE AC
- RAM: 2x 32Gb Corsair DDR4-2666 in slots 2 and 4

**What can I do to identify the cause of the freezes?**

### Edit

Today the PC froze again, and I was monitoring it from another PC using HWINFO. Here are the last values from the sensors. I can't see anything suspicious here:

[image: Screenshot of HWINFO]

Comment: To check if the display driver is the cause : Once the freeze happens, use the key combination Win+Ctrl+Shift+B to refresh the driver.

Comment: I'll try that when it freezes again. When the PC freezes the keyboard seems to stop responding, though (caps lock no longer lights the led), so I'm not sure it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You have performed commendable testing. You've also noted the issue seems to be related to *heat*, both environmental and due to high CPU and/or GPU load.

1. Confirm that it is heat. Use a tool such as [HWinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/hwinfo32/) to check CPU and GPU temperatures.

[image: HWinfo64 Temp Sensors]

2. It could be heat ids affecting another component, such as a marginal power supply. You might try **gently** warming the PC with a hair dryer to see if that causes "freezing" (hmm... odd inversion of meaning).
3. Have you (or someone else) made any changes, such as **[overclocking](https://www.msi.com/blog/intel-9th-cpu-overclocking-5ghz-with-z390-motherboards)**, that might be causing overheating? If so, roll back somewhat. Note that *HWinfo* also displays system timing, voltage and other settings in *great* detail.
4. Carefully [clean](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Computer_System_Cleaning) everything, particularly heat-sinks and fans. Though some recommend removing CPU and GPU, reapplying thermal compound and reinstalling, there are **many** posts online on how to repair *damage* done by doing that procedure (and they often involve *replacing* expensive parts) -- I'd avoid trying that "repair".
5. If after all this, the system still is affected by heat, consider substituting an alternate power supply. Borrow rather than buy, since it might not be the cause.

Comment: Usually the CPU core temperatures oscillate between 45ºC in the morning and 60ºC when the day gets warmer. I just did a CPU stress test and the temperature reached almost 100ºC, but I suppose that's expected when doing such tests. In any case the system remained stable. I'll try warming the PC later when I'm not working.

About overclocking, I didn't overclock the PC and I'm pretty sure that it isn't because I build it myself with.

I've recently cleaned the heat sinks and fans and that didn't help. I even replaced the thermal paste of the CPU, but the problem remains.

Comment: Regarding the power supply, I can try replacing it, but I don't have anyone who can lend me one. The only option would be to buy one. All components were purchased new about 3 years ago.

Comment: @AntoineAubry, good testing and cleaning, again. Since you stress tested both GPU and CPU, and even reached 100ºC on CPU and it *didn't* shut down, likely it's not heat affecting those two. One more idea: does your area have *brownouts* (power reduction ) or unstable mains power during hot weather? If so, try an uninterruptible power supply (UPS).

Comment: that's something I didn't consider. I don't know if there are brownouts in this area, although I never see the lights flicker or anything similar.

Comment: Today the PC froze again, and I was monitoring it from another PC using HWINFO. I've added are the last values from the sensors, but I can't see anything suspicious.

Comment: @AntoineAubry After reading everything in this thread, I think there is a physical problem with one component in your hardware. IMO thermal expansion is making some random component to misbehave. Also there could be a component or pin with corrosion(more heat, less stable voltage).

Comment: @dmb Any tips on how to find out which one? There's not much that I can disconnect, but I'll check all connectors. Perhaps one of them is slightly loose or something.

Comment: @AntoineAubry You will need to disassemble the pc and check for corrosion. On the other hand figuring which component is having problem is more difficult as it could be a resistor or a single capacitor having issues.

Comment: anecdotal, but if you have a PSU with removable/modular cabling, try moving the GPU cable to a different connector on the PSU if available.